# Invalid Syntax in python simple functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def terfi_ettir(kisi,e_poz,y_poz,e_maas,z_orani):

    print("%s,%s pozisyonundan %s pozisyonuna terfi etmiştir" %(kisi,e_poz,y_poz)) 
    print("bu kisinin %s TL olan maasi %s TL ye yükseltilmiştir." %(e_maas,e_maas+(e_maas*z_orani/100))

terfi_ettir("Ahmet Öncel","iş geliştirme uzmanı","iş geliştirme müdürü",3500,25)
```

what's wrong with this simple function, it says there's an invalid syntax in the last line.

Comment: You seem to be missing an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the preceding line:

```
print("bu kisinin %s TL olan maasi %s TL ye yükseltilmiştir." %
      (e_maas,e_maas+(e_maas*z_orani/100))
#                                 --------^
```

The `print()` function is not closed, only the string formatting tuple is.